# How to call a java class using mysql trigger

Tags: java, mysql, triggers, synchronization

I was developing a code to sync data between multiple servers.

I wrote this MySQL trigger, so that it would trigger a java program if any change occurs to the table and sync it over to other servers.

If I run the below SQL code, I won't get any error and the java class is not being called.

```
    use server1;
    drop trigger if exists datainsert;
    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER datainsert
    AFTER INSERT ON `student` FOR EACH ROW
    begin
           DECLARE id_exists Boolean;
           DECLARE a INT;
           SELECT 1
           INTO @id_exists
           FROM student
           WHERE student.user_name= NEW.user_name;

           IF @id_exists = 1
           THEN
              set a = sys_exec("java -cp \"E:\\servers\\Tomcat_instance1\\webapps\\Server\\lib\\*;E:\\servers\\Tomcat_instance1\\webapps\\Server\\WEB-INF\\classes;\" Test");
    END IF;
    END;
    $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

**Insert query**

```
    use server1;
    SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
    insert into student values('l5','Test@123','asd','asd','M','20','coimbatore','654321','9876543210','a@123.com')
```

What am I missing here?

I have correctly linked the required library `(lib_mysqludf_sys)` file.